# Python stock quotes and all time highs and lows

Tags: curl, yahoo-finance, google-finance

The curl one liner below generates the stock price,  but I would also like to have 2 columns next to it so that I can get the all time high and all time low of the stock as well.

Using the below from commadlinefu :

curl -s 'http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=csco&f=l1'
23.445

But would be good to have some context to see where it is in relation to it previous all time high and previous all time lows.

Any thoughts ??

Comment: What python script? What have you tried? `curl` is not a python script as far as I know...

Comment: apologies this has been amended I meant to say curl